# Why os.system() in script fails?

Tags: python

I have a script containing a line of the type:

```
os.system('file.exe <arg>')
```

`file.exe` makes some calculations taking `<arg>` as input and writes an output file. `<arg>` is a file containing parameter values located in the same folder as `file.exe`.

The instruction, if executed independently in Python IDLE, works well. However, when executing the script in IDLE it fails. That is, a Windows shell window flashes, but no output file is written. There is a similar behaviour with `os.popen()` and `subprocess.call()`. Everything works well in Spyder on another computer.

I was wondering which might be the reason for this behaviour.

Comment: Where are these files located? Have you tried to put the full path to `<arg>` rather than just the filename?

Comment: Have you tried using [subprocess.check_call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)? That should give you a traceback with an error in case the process (file.exe) fails.

Comment: @SiHa: both files are located in the working directory and I have put the full path to `<arg>`, but there is no change.

Comment: Is the script run from the same directory as well?

Comment: So... All three files (`script.py`, `file.exe`, `<arg>`) are located in the same directory?

Comment: @SiHa, @Anand S Kumar: no the script is run in one directory (included the path) and `file.exe`and `<arg>` in another.

Comment: The scripts works now, but I am not sure why. Maybe the question should be closed?